How to install ROS2 on the robot (NAOiq OS)?
I came across https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Cross-compilation.html to install ROS2 on the nao robot, but then what is the target architecture of the software, how to install ROS2 on NAOiq OS? is https://github.com/docker/buildx?tab=readme-ov-file#building-multi-platform-images the best approach?
